# Simple explanation of offset term for logistic regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, algorithms, offset

In simple words, how we can force any logistic regression coefficient be 1.  Is there any steps/algorithm that used behind offset term?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking.

Comment: I am confused that how we force coefficent to be 1. For example, in regression lm((y-x1)~1) it will force coeffcient of x1 be 1. How we use this trick in logisitic regression?

Comment: Yes I can add there, but what is algorithm or trick behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "trick" behind the use of an offset term ( * ), while the other coefficients will be estimated, that is, their values will be updated at each step of the IRLS ( * ) fitting algorithm, the offset coefficient will not be updated, it will keep its value of 1.

( * ) IRLS is iteratively reweighted least squares, the fitting algorithm usually used for generalized linear models such as logistic regression.  For an overview, see [Can you give a simple intuitive explanation of IRLS method to find the MLE of a GLM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384)

The offset term is included with a term `offset(x1)` in the model formula, or via the use of a separate `offset=`  argument. The first way is the preferred one. This will force the coefficient of `x1` to be one.